# Apache solr: new schema.xml or single predefined xml data format

Tags: search, solr

I am trying to create a search engine using solr.For that I first started with Wikipedia page article dump.

Now as I gone through solrs documentation almost half way, but could not able to answer few doubts of mine which are below?

1- I found that I need to create schema.xml using which tokenizing and extraction of data will be performed. For one data source it seems fine but should I write this schema.xml everytime when I add new data source.

2- If answer of 1 is yes (i.e. You need to write seperate schema.xml everytime), then I have to add new cores everytime whenever I add new data source which seems me impractical.So my question is how Google, Bing and other search engine achieve it.

3- If answer of 1 is no, then possible way seems me that I can covert information from different sources to a common format which I will send for indexing to Sorl?

Please let me know how exactly search engine are build? What should be expected approaches?

I am looking for some article for my questions continuously but not getting relevant information regarding the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the search world most the data is unstructured or semi-structured. So defining a single generic schema would be very hard. I am assuming you must have some fair idea about what all different type of datasets you will be indexing to solr. That will give you some understanding about basic/common fields which you can declare in your solr schema configuration.

Solr provide great deal of flexibility for defining schema for unknown field using [`Dynamic Fields`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Dynamic+Fields). The `Dynamic Fields` are same as regular fields in all aspects except their names end with wild-cards. So they can accommodate large set of unknown fields in incoming data which we are not aware at the moment. The following can index anything ending with **`t`**.

```
<dynamicField name="*_t" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Another approach could be using solr's [`Schema-less`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schemaless+Mode) mode. In this mode, solr will keep guessing the field types and adds them to the managed schema file. You can even use this approach just to understand the nature (schema) of your different datasets and later use these insights, to create near stable schema for your final version of the product. This can help you finding a lot more unknowns in your datasets.